# Ubuntu image that is in the AWS AMI Marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04

We want to use the exact same image that AWS uses for their Ubuntu AMI in order to build a docker image from it. The problem is that we don't know what EXACT version they use.

Is it the cloud or server edition of Ubuntu (xenial 16.04)?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! There is an "EC2 tarbal" in the description of one image here:
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release-20180126/